# creating a matrix with a nested for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

This is a practice question to prep for an exam. I'm given the following code:

```
     W=matrix(1:16,byrow=T,ncol=4)
print(W)

fmat=function(W){
n=nrow(W)

      for (i in 1:n){
      for (j in 1:n){
        W[j,i]=W[i,j]+W[j,i]
      }
      }

      return(W)
}

print(fmat(W))
```

We have to "run" the code on paper and then check our answers by running the code in R. I wrote out the correct matrix for W but I got fmat(W) wrong. R gives me the following output for fmat(W):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15   21
[2,]    7   12   24   30
[3,]   12   17   22   39
[4,]   17   22   27   32
```

where I had written down that fmat(W) would equal:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    7   12   17
[2,]    7   12   17   22
[3,]   12   17   22   27
[4,]   17   22   27   32
```

What exactly is going on here? I had interpreted the function to calculate that, for example, w[2,1]=w[1,2]+w[2,1], which is 2+5=7.

Answer (score 0):

In you code, `W` is overwritten in your nested `for` loop by columns and then by rows.

To visualize the progress, you can add `print(W)` before your value assignment `W[j,i] = W[i,j]+W[j,i]`, i.e.,

```
fmat=function(W){
  n=nrow(W)
  for (i in 1:n){
    for (j in 1:n){
      print(W)
      W[j,i]=W[i,j]+W[j,i]
    }
  }
  return(W)
}
```

such that

```
> fmat(W)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    3    4
[2,]    7    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    3    4
[2,]    7    6    7    8
[3,]   12   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    3    4
[2,]    7    6    7    8
[3,]   12   10   11   12
[4,]   17   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9    3    4
[2,]    7    6    7    8
[3,]   12   10   11   12
[4,]   17   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9    3    4
[2,]    7   12    7    8
[3,]   12   10   11   12
[4,]   17   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9    3    4
[2,]    7   12    7    8
[3,]   12   17   11   12
[4,]   17   14   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9    3    4
[2,]    7   12    7    8
[3,]   12   17   11   12
[4,]   17   22   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15    4
[2,]    7   12    7    8
[3,]   12   17   11   12
[4,]   17   22   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15    4
[2,]    7   12   24    8
[3,]   12   17   11   12
[4,]   17   22   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15    4
[2,]    7   12   24    8
[3,]   12   17   22   12
[4,]   17   22   15   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15    4
[2,]    7   12   24    8
[3,]   12   17   22   12
[4,]   17   22   27   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15   21
[2,]    7   12   24    8
[3,]   12   17   22   12
[4,]   17   22   27   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15   21
[2,]    7   12   24   30
[3,]   12   17   22   12
[4,]   17   22   27   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15   21
[2,]    7   12   24   30
[3,]   12   17   22   39
[4,]   17   22   27   16
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    9   15   21
[2,]    7   12   24   30
[3,]   12   17   22   39
[4,]   17   22   27   32
```

Comment: The code was written by my professor, who wants us to understand how the code arrives at the output it arrives at. We're supposed to look at the code and write out on paper what the matrix in the output is going to be, then check our answer with R. We are probably going to have a similar question on the exam, so I need to understand how I can calculate fmat(W) with my brain and a calculator the same way R does it with the code provided.

Comment: @Emily see my updates and hope it can help you understand